# $x\equiv y\text{ mod }P^j$ for all $j$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field. Let $R$ be the ring of integers of $K$. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$. Let $x,y\in R$ be such that $x\equiv y\text{ mod }P^j$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$. Can we conclude that $x=y$ ?

Comment: Hint: consider the element $x - y$. In what ideals does it lie?

Comment: It lies in $\cap_jP^j$ and $P^j$'s form a decreasing sequence of ideals.

Comment: Certainly. Do you know anything about this ideal? What elements does it contain?

Comment: I have an idea. Correct me if I am wrong. We know that if $I$ is any ideal and $a\in I$, then norm of $I$ divides norm of $a$. This means that norm of $x-y$ is divisible by $\|P\|^j$ for all arbitrarily large $j$. This proves that $x-y=0$.

Comment: All non-zero ideals factor uniquely into a finite product of prime powers, clearly $\cap P^j$ has infinite factors, hence it must be the $0$ ideal. Hence...